# What does cd -- do? I used it and I'm now stuck in a directory :(

Tags: command-line, cd-command

I entered `cd --` into the terminal, just to see what I'd get...

It brought me here: `~ #` (I'm root btw).

Just wondering where exactly I am - if I enter `ls` the output is:

```
Desktop
```

`ls -a`:

```
.          .bash_history  .config  .loki        .q3a
..         .bazaar        .dbus    .kbd        .macromedia  .synaptic
.adobe     .bzr.log       Desktop  .panda3d     .wine
.aptitude  .cache         .gconf   .local      .profile
```

I can't `cd` into `home`, `/` or anything else - and I can't get out of the folder **:'(**

Would be nice to know what I just did...

Comment: You are in the `/root`

Comment: @Pilot6 how do you/I know?

Comment: By the prompt. `~#` is `/root`.

Comment: And there is no problem to do e.g. `cd /home`

Comment: Do "pwd" to see where you are.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `--` is interpreted as "no more options following", see more in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11382/87495). So the command is equivalent to `cd`, which switches to the current user's home directory.

As you reported, you end up with a prompt of `... ~ #`, which, with default config means that you are logged in as the root user and that you currently are in root's home directory (`~` is a shortcut for a user's home).

On a default Ubuntu setup, the home of root is `/root`. So `cd`ing to `home` doesn't work, as you are not in the root directory and therefore the shell doesn't know where to go. But you should always be able to `cd /`. Are you sure you entered that command correctly?

Comment: I'm not sure your first paragraph is technically accurate . Bash doesn't "interpret" `--`, it's handled as part of the application argument parsing.

Comment: Of course, you're right ;) I'll change it.

Comment: @Oli's remark is 100% spot on since not clarifying that is potentially misleading, however the funny fact is that in this case it's not inaccurate to say that Bash handles it, since `cd` is a built-in (hence part of Bash). You may well say that Bash handles it, but you should also make it clear that this is because `cd` is part of Bash.

Answer (score 2):

The command `pwd` will output your present working directory (where you are).

@pilot6 is probably right - you are in `/root` given your `ls` output.